# Double binary search algorithm

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a double binary search problem for my research project ([The algorithm could be found here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221349779_Fast_Intersection_Algorithms_for_Sorted_Sequences) on page 49). Each if/else part of the code would work well by itself, but when I tried putting them together, the whole code will result in an infinite loop.

The interactive link of the code is [here](https://repl.it/@NguyenQuang/ImaginativeColdDivisor), I've used printf to debug if you want to take a look

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int binary_search(vector<int>& pos, int start, int end, int num, int& found)
{
    if (start > end) {
        //eventually will return position that the number is supposed to be in if not found
        return start;
    } else {
        int mid = start + (end - start)/2;

        if (pos[mid] == num) {
            found = 1;
            return mid;
        }
        if (pos[mid] < num) {
            return binary_search(pos, mid + 1, end, num, found);
        }
        else {
            return binary_search(pos, start, mid - 1, num, found);
        }
    }
}

vector<int> double_binary_search(vector<int>& vec_2, vector<int>& vec_1, int start_vec_2, int end_vec_2, int start_vec_1, int end_vec_1) 
{

    vector<int> intersection;
    if (end_vec_2 < start_vec_2 or end_vec_1 < start_vec_1) {
        return {};
    }

    int mid_vec_1 = start_vec_1 + (end_vec_1 - start_vec_1)/2;
    int mid_vec_1_val = vec_1[mid_vec_1];
    int found = 0;

    int mid_vec_2 = binary_search (vec_2, start_vec_2, end_vec_2, mid_vec_1_val, found);

    vector<int> res;
    //size of left 2 > size of left 1
    if ((mid_vec_2 - start_vec_2) > (mid_vec_1 - start_vec_1)) {
        res = double_binary_search(vec_2, vec_1, start_vec_2, mid_vec_2, start_vec_1, mid_vec_1);
        intersection.insert(intersection.end(), res.begin(), res.end());
    }

    else if ((mid_vec_2 - start_vec_2) <= (mid_vec_1 - start_vec_1)){// we exchange the roles of big vec and small vec
        res = double_binary_search(vec_1, vec_2, start_vec_1, mid_vec_1, start_vec_2, mid_vec_2);
        intersection.insert(intersection.end(), res.begin(), res.end());
    }   

    if (found == 1) {
        mid_vec_2++;
    }

    if ((end_vec_2 - mid_vec_2) > (end_vec_1 - mid_vec_1)) {
        res = double_binary_search(vec_2, vec_1, mid_vec_2, end_vec_2, mid_vec_1 + 1, end_vec_1);
        intersection.insert(intersection.end(), res.begin(), res.end());
    }

    else {// we exchange the roles of big vec and small vec
        vector<int> res = double_binary_search(vec_1, vec_2, mid_vec_1, end_vec_1, mid_vec_2 + 1, end_vec_2);
        intersection.insert(intersection.end(), res.begin(), res.end());
    }

    return intersection;

}

int main() 
{
    vector<int> vec_2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25};
    vector<int> vec_1 = {0,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18};
    vector<int> sample = {11};
    vector<int> intersection = double_binary_search(vec_2, vec_1, 0, vec_2.size() - 1, 0, vec_1.size() - 1);  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I've used printf to debug* -- Use a debugger.  Using just `printf` can only get you so far.  In addition, misuses of `printf` could output erroneous results.

Comment: Your code produces a stack overflow, not just an infinite loop.  Second, you should use the [std::binary_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) and/or [std::lower_bound/upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) to make sure it isn't a buggy home-made binary_search that is causing the issue.

Comment: I did make the change, and it's still not working correctly. My former home-made binary search also works so I don't believe that is the problem. Any base case that you can think of? I think I'm missing a base case or a condition check here and there that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `start_vec_1 == end_vec_1` and `start_vec_2 == end_vec_2`, you'll recursively call `double_binary_search` with the same parameters (albeit swapping vec1 and vec2) since the `else if` condition will be true.  This will continue until you run out of stack space.

You need to adjust that condition so that you don't recurse all the time, and/or adjust the values (limits) being passed to the recursive call.